# Jqgrid custom load

Tags: javascript, json, jqgrid

I am loading two json data as below during the start up.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loaddata1();    

});
$(document).ready(function() {
loaddata2();    
});
```

Both these are shown in two grids. jQuery("#grid1").jqGrid and jQuery("#grid2").jqGrid

At this moment both these grids are being load when the page loads first time.

What I need is to create hyperlink so that when we hit that link the second grid is loaded as a popup and not in the first page?

Just FYI I have already tried "name:'id', index:'id', key: true, width:90, formatter:'showlink',formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'#'"
in one of the column so that, by clicking that value I should load "#grid2", as a popup. But didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution.
Use **JQXWindow** to show your grid as a popup and then you can show whatever you want in that window. Refer below link.
http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxwindow/index.htm#demos/jqxwindow/defaultfunctionality.htm